# Upload and Play Any Video in web browser using php CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg, video-player

I have tried to upload any video and convert the video file to mp4 at the time of upload using ffmpeg. The shell command I tried:

```
$input = base_url().'video_upload/'.$file_name;
$output = video_upload/video_'.$video_data['username'].'_'.$dtd.'_'.$random_number.'.mp4';
$convt = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$input.' '.$output);
```

But i am unable to play those converted video in the web browser.

Comment: You should check ffmpeg's documentation on how to correctly convert videos into playable mp4's. Since you're using ffmpeg's shell command, your issue is with that, not your PHP.

Comment: Btw, isn't `base_url()` the url and not the path, which is what you should be using?

Comment: will you please let me know the browser playable format of mp4 video file

Comment: Just google: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support. You should also check that the video got converted correctly. Have you tried playing it on your computer?

Comment: See: [What bunch of ffmpeg scripts do I need to get HTML5-compatible "Video for everybody"? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-get-html5-compatible-video-for-everyb)

Comment: I am done. Thank everyone for your guidance